# Is there a way to set an existing connection into an entityManager

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, entitymanager

I have a connection handler that provides a connection for me:
Here the code

```
handle = (JDBCHandler) m_broker.getBroker().getConnection();
Connection conn = handle.getConnection();
```

I want to grap this connection and use it inside the entityManager and continuing dealing with the entityManger functions.

Is there a way to do that please?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think it's very usual to try this but..

Since you're using Hibernate you could try using the **reconnect** method from Hibernate [Session](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#reconnect%28java.sql.Connection%29).

First you need to unwrap your [EntityManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) (to get Hibernate's underlying implementation) and then use the reconnect method that takes a Connection object:

```
entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).reconnect(connection);
```

Comment: I am trying this, but getting an error: Cannot manually reconnect unless Connection was originally supplied. Any idea?